# Entity framework. Traer entidad de clave foránea

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

Tengo estas dos tablas en SqlServer:

```
USE [MYDB]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TipoElemento](
    [TipoElementoId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Descripcion] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TipoElemento] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [TipoElementoId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO


USE [MYDB]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Elemento](
    [ElementoId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Nombre] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [TipoElementoId] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Elemento] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ElementoId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Elemento]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Elemento_TipoElemento] FOREIGN KEY([TipoElementoId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[TipoElemento] ([TipoElementoId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Elemento] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Elemento_TipoElemento]
GO
```

Y estas entidades definidas:

```
public class TipoElemento
   {
      int TipoElementoId { get; set; }
      public string Descripcion { get; set; }
   }

   public class Elemento
   {
      public int ElementoId { get; set; }
      public string Nombre { get; set; }
      public int TipoElementoId { get; set; }
      public virtual TipoElemento TipoElemento { get; set; }
   }
```

Estoy utilizando SqlServer, Entityframework core 3.1.6 y C# con .NET Core 3.1

Cuando me traigo la lista de entidades Elemento, quiero que también se traiga el TipoElemento, sin embargo este último me viene a null.
En el DbContext las tengo definidas así:

```
public DbSet<TipoElemento> TiposElemento { get; set; }
public DbSet<Elemento> Elementos { get; set; }
```

En el modelbuilder he probado con esta configuración:

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Elemento> builder)
{
  builder.HasOne(x => x.TipoElemento).WithOne();
}
```

y me sigue trayendo la lista de Elementos sin informarme el TipoElemento.
Cómo podría configurarlo para que me traiga los elementos junto con su tipo?

Comment: Intenta agregar la colección `public ICollection<Elemento> Elementos { get; set; }` a la clase `TipoElemento`. en el builder de `Elemento`: `bulder.HasOne(x=>x.TipoElemento).WithMany(x=>x.Elementos);`. En el builder de `TipoElemento`: `builder.HasMany(x=>x.Elementos).WithOne(x=> x.TipoElemento)`. Es una relación 1 a muchos. Si pones "`HasOne().HasOne()`", parece que es uno a uno. Más información [en este enlace](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¿Estás realizando la consulta con `linq`?

Si quieres traer las referencias foráneas, debes de usar el `include`

```
Elemento.Include(x=>x.TipoElemento ).ToList();
```

Así te trae el objeto secundario referenciado.

Comment: Gracias. Esto me funcionó perfecto.